# entity framework foreign key where dependent key is not the primary key

Tags: entity-framework-6, fluent-interface

I have two tables, the dependent table has a foreign key which is not the primary key. This is a 0 to 1 relationship. How do I set up the association with entity framework 6, code first, fluent API? The tables already exist in the db.

```cs
public class Formula
{
    public int Id { get; set; } /*Primary key*/
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MayHaveAFormula
{
    public int Id { get; set; } /*Primary key*/
    public int? FormulaId { get; set; } /*links to Formula.Id */
    public Formula Formula { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> This is a 0 to 1 relationship

No, it isn't. You *want* it to be, but it is a one-to-many relationship. When an entity has an independent foreign key (i.e. not also being its primary key) you can't model it as a 1:1 association in EF.

So you model this as a regular 1:n association and in business logic you enforce it's 1:1.

On thing you can do to help enforce 1:1 is to create a unique index on the `FormulaId` field. Now the database will throw an ugly exception when you try to create a second `MayHaveAFormula` for a `Formula`. Of course this shouldn't replace business logic, but it's an extra safeguard.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  So the best I can do is something like: HasOptional(fsa => fsa.Formula).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.FormulaId);  - for the config for MayHaveFormulaClass ?

Comment: Yes, that's the standard 1:n mapping.